# How do I check chronoboost usage, and whether or not it is being saved when scouting Protoss?

Tags: starcraft-2

I often scout with an early probe - 9 or 12, but although I recognise how important it is, I don't actually know how to tell how much Chronoboost is being saved by my opponent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is to click on the Nexus. You can see the energy they have. If you have health bars on, you don't even have to click on it at all.

Comment: Or hold down the *Alt* key.

Comment: Good comment, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of clicking on the Nexus - press 'Alt' button. In 'default' case you will see all units/buildings health/energy bar. That is more useful.

Comment: Why does this have two down votes?

Comment: @Wipqozn Because this has already been said in another answer and comments?

Comment: Which is a good reason to not give it up votes.. but not a good reason to down vote it.